# Splitting binary file on tags?

Tags: java, binaryfiles, mod-security, logparser

I have a ModSecurity log file which contains parts which contain either text or binary data. I need to split this file according to the tags which are noted at the start of each part so i can do filtering of data for permanent storage.

So for example I have:

```
--tag1--
<text>
--tag2--
<binary data>
--tag3--
<text>
```

At first I thought it was all text so i made a parser to parse all the different pieces by reading the line and using a pattern to check if it was a new part. But now I need to read the file in binary. So what would be the best way to achieve this?

So far i've made a test to get a specific part by keeping the last several characters in a String buffer to check for the string and then start printing when the buffer contains that string. The same is done to stop. However since the buffer needs to fill up before it can check the end tag, the end tag will have been added to the byte array so once the part is complete, I remove the final bytes from the array to get the part needed.

```
public byte[] binaryDataReader(String startTag, String endTag) throws IOException{
        File file = new File("20160926-161148-V@ksog7ZjVRfyQUPtAdOmgAAAAM");

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());

            int content;
            String lastChars = "";
            String status = "nok";
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                if (lastChars.length() > 14) {
                    lastChars = lastChars.substring(lastChars.length() - 14, lastChars.length()) + (char) content;
                } else {
                    lastChars += (char) content;
                }
                if(status.equals("ok")){
                    buffer.write(content);
                }
                if (lastChars.equals(startTag)) {
                    status = "ok";
                }else if(lastChars.equals(endTag)){
                    status = "nok";
                }
            }
            buffer.flush();
            byte[] data = buffer.toByteArray();
            data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length-15);
            return data;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Now i need to make this a general solution for many more tags by including patterns. But I was wondering: Is this a decent way of splitting a binary file or is there a better/easier way to achieve this?

Comment: I might miss something but why do you treat text files as binary? Note that you can't just cast an int to char unless you are very sure that the encoding used to write that file allows it (imagine an UTF-8 encoded file). Besides that I'd not use statements like `lastChars += ...;` here since strings are immutable and you'll generate a new instance for each added character that way. Better (re)use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Part of the text file is binary. So unless i read it as binary I will be missing bytes when i start reading the binary part. I know which part is binary and which isn't. Also if the byte is casted to a char and it is not a readable char, it doesn't really matter much and the reader will just pass over it since the buffer is only used to check for the tag and nothing else.

Correct the buffer can be written better. This was just a quick solution. I will be using a StringBuilder in the final version for optimal performance.

Comment: The encoding problem might still exist or are you absolutely sure that only ASCII characters can be encountered? Besides that you might want to convert your tags to byte patterns (e.g. by using a byte array and the correct encoding) and look for those. Thus you'd not have to convert the input to string just for a check.

Comment: Well I have many more tags to check so this will be done using a pattern instead of actual tags. I have been looking on the net if there is a way to use patterns to check byte arrays but so far I have only found that it is not possible. How would you suggest me doing it in that case? My pattern is as follows: "^--.*-(\w)--$". In case of bytes the beginning of line and the end of line tag would be replaced by newline ("\n", etc) tags of course.